# Transaction committed partially in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, commit, sql-delete, rollback

I have case that some table row is deleted mysteriously. So I created a delete trigger to get hints what really happen.

I found that a stored procedure to delete is executed. This delete stored procedure has three consecutive transactions, but only delete shipping detail table, update barcode status and barcode log not executed.

I don't know how it partially committed or failed to rollback.

Here is the delete stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSLSdelShippingDetail]
    @DetailInternalID int,
    @BarcodeInternalID int ,  
    @UserModified varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Issued bit
    DECLARE @IssuedTo int
    DECLARE @InternalID int 
    DECLARE @BarcodeWarehouse int
    DECLARE @ShippingWarehouse int

    DECLARE @IssuedShipping varchar(50) = (SELECT InternalID 
                                           FROM dbo.M_IssuedTo 
                                           WHERE [Description] = 'Shipping')
    DECLARE @InvInternalID int = (SELECT InvInternalID 
                                  FROM T_InventoryBarcode 
                                  WHERE InternalID = @BarcodeInternalID)  
  
    --Get Header Warehouse
    SELECT @ShippingWarehouse = WHInternalID 
    FROM T_ShippingHeader 
    WHERE InternalID = (SELECT ShippingInternalID 
                        FROM T_ShippingDetail 
                        WHERE DetailInternalID = @DetailInternalID)

    --Get Issued, IssuedTo, and Warehouse (Barcode)
    SELECT 
        @InternalID = TBH1.InternalID,
        @Issued = TBH1.Issued,
        @IssuedTo = TBH1.IssuedToInternalID,
        @BarcodeWarehouse = IVB.WHInternalID 
    FROM 
        T_BarcodeHistory AS TBH1
    JOIN 
        T_InventoryBarcode AS IVB ON TBH1.BarcodeInternalID = IVB.InternalID  
    WHERE 
        TBH1.BarcodeInternalID = @BarcodeInternalID 
        AND TBH1.InternalID = (SELECT MAX(TBH2.InternalID) 
                               FROM T_BarcodeHistory AS TBH2 
                               WHERE TBH2.BarcodeInternalID = TBH1.BarcodeInternalID)

    IF @Issued = 1 
       AND @IssuedTo = @IssuedShipping 
       AND @BarcodeWarehouse = @ShippingWarehouse  
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION [delete];

            DECLARE @ROWCOUNT int = 0

            DELETE FROM T_ShippingDetail
            WHERE DetailInternalID = @DetailInternalID

            SET @ROWCOUNT = @ROWCOUNT + @@ROWCOUNT

            UPDATE T_BarcodeHistory
            SET Issued = 0,
                IssuedToInternalID = IssuedToInternalIDBefore,
                UserModified = ISNULL(@UserModified, ''),
                dtModified = GETDATE()   
            WHERE InternalID = @InternalID 

            SET @ROWCOUNT = @ROWCOUNT + @@ROWCOUNT
 
            INSERT INTO T_LogBarcode (BarcodeInternalID, InvInternalID, Tanggal, Remark, Status, UserName, dtRecord, UserModified, dtModified, rowguid)  
            VALUES (@BarcodeInternalID, @InvInternalID, GETDATE(), 'Shipping', 'Delete', @UserModified, GETDATE(), @UserModified, GETDATE(), NEWID())  

            SET @ROWCOUNT = @ROWCOUNT + @@ROWCOUNT
            
            DECLARE @M varchar(50) = 'Unexpected error!' + CAST(@ROWCOUNT AS varchar(50))

            IF (@ROWCOUNT <> 3) 
                 RAISERROR (@m, 11, 1);  

            COMMIT TRANSACTION [delete];
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            THROW;  
        END CATCH;
    END
    ELSE  
    BEGIN  
        DECLARE @BarcodeID varchar(50) = (SELECT BarcodeID 
                                          FROM T_InventoryBarcode 
                                          WHERE InternalID = @BarcodeInternalID)  

        DECLARE @Msg varchar(max) = 'Delete is not allowed! BarcodeID ''[Barcode]'' is already used for another process!' 
        SET @Msg = REPLACE(@Msg, '[Barcode]', @BarcodeID)  
        RAISERROR (@Msg, 11, 1);  
    END 
END
```

And here is the AFTER DELETE TRIGGER

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_ShippingDetail_Delete]
   ON  [dbo].[T_ShippingDetail]
   AFTER Delete
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @ExecStr varchar(50), @Qry nvarchar(255)

    CREATE TABLE #inputbuffer 
    (
      EventType nvarchar(30), 
      Parameters int, 
      EventInfo nvarchar(max)
    )

    SET @ExecStr = 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + STR(@@SPID) + ')'

    INSERT INTO #inputbuffer 
    EXEC (@ExecStr)

    SET @Qry = (SELECT EventInfo FROM #inputbuffer)

    INSERT INTO T_TransactionLog(TransactionType,DetailInternalID,ReferenceInternalID,BarcodeInternalID,Qty,UoM,QtyPack,UoMPack,
     Price,Price2,Disc,SubTotal,ValueAddedTax,IncomeTaxID,IncomeTaxPercentage,IncomeTax,Remarks,CropYear,UserName,dtRecord,
     UserModified,dtModified,dtDeleted,rowguid,InternalNote)
    SELECT 'T_ShippingDetail',DetailInternalID,ShippingInternalID,BarcodeInternalID,NULL,UoM,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
     NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Remarks,CropYear,UserName,dtRecord,UserModified,dtModified,
     GETDATE(),rowguid,'ShippingInternalID :' + cast(shippingInternalID as varchar(50)) +
     ' - NT LOGIN NAME ' + SUSER_NAME() +' '+ ISNULL(@Qry, '')

    FROM DELETED


END
```

Can anyone help me to show what really happened?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know the procedure is the culprit. Much more likely something else just deleted a row. Unless your trigger does something weird with commits the Tran shouldn't get partialized.

Comment: I created after delete trigger to know which store procedure deleted the row. `SET @ExecStr = 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + STR(@@SPID) + ')'

    INSERT INTO #inputbuffer 
    EXEC (@ExecStr)

    SET @Qry = (SELECT EventInfo FROM #inputbuffer)`  and I get `ShippingInternalID :73537 - NT LOGIN NAME XXXX\mkt.xxxxxx xxxxxx.dbo.spSLSdelShippingDetail;1`

Comment: Hmm. Can you put whole trigger code in the question?

Comment: Speculation - you've got everything in a `try/catch` block but affecting 0 rows on any of those DML statements isn't an error. So the only way a rollback would happen is if an actual error (e.g. FK violation) happens.

Comment: @BenThul `IF (@ROWCOUNT <> 3) 
                 RAISERROR (@m, 11, 1); ` this section actually trigger try/catch. I have tested that this `raiserror` can trigger try/catch

Comment: if you run this code "normally", does it work? I have very hard to believe you can get this problem, due to how transactions work. Is there an outer procedure with own transaction handling?

Comment: I don't have access to your table definitions, but is it possible that any of those statements could affect more than one row? i.e. it seems like you're implicitly expecting your three statements to affect one row a piece, but what if the statements affect (for example) 2, 1, and 0 rows? The total rows affected would be 3 but not in the way you expect.

Comment: @siggemannen I also currious there are some bug with .NET. I think should be the other store procedure, But every time this bug happen, after delete trigger always show this delete sp. There are no outer or inner store procedure.

Comment: @Benthul `DetailInternalID` is a primary Key, its unique. `BarcodeInternalID`on `T_BarcodeHistory` is foreign key, this is one to one relation. But, I will try your suggestion with checking every affected row, `if <> 0 then raiserror`. Let's see few more days. Thanks

Comment: Even if row count mismatched there would be a raiserror leading to a full rollback, no?

Answer (score -1):

Because of all your variables values are out of the scope of the transaction, some change can be done, after the variables has been assigned and before the delete / udpate in the transaction execute.

It is a bad pratice to separate a transaction in pieces some of the reads of tables in the data out the scope of the final explicit transaction.

The result can be inconsistent...

Put all the SELECT code into subqueries in the final UPDATE/DELETE first and I think many of your actual trouble will disapear...

Comment: "It is a bad pratice (sic)..." Can you elaborate? I would propose a counterpoint in that there are merits to keeping the transaction scope as narrow as possible to mitigate concurrency issues is worthwhile.

Comment: Between phase 1 (that assign variable) and phase 2 (the explicit transaction) of the code processed, data can be changed by concurrent users. So the code into the explicit transaction can have some side effects... To avoid some of theese effects you need to promote the transaction to a higher level of isolation and encapsulate the all code into the explicit transaction... ! Or integrate SELECT subqueries into the main DELETE / UPDATE queries

Comment: You're right. But that's a choice and not "bad" or "good" on its own. That transaction isolation levels exist at all suggests (to me at least) that concurrency vs isolation tradeoffs have been baked into the standard for a very long time.

Comment: I will try this solution by wrapping all variable declaration and transaction. Let's see it a week later. Thanks !